# Qt undefined reference to dependence of static library

Tags: qt, static, undefined

I've got static library, which is using some functions from `setupapi.lib`, so it has `LIBS += -lsetupapi` in its .pro file.

Library itself builds just fine.

Now, I have Qt app which is using functions from that static lib, and when I try to compile it, I get errors like:

> undefined reference to `*imp*_SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryPropertyW@28'

I've added `LIBS += -lsetupapi` info app's .pro file, but it did not help.

I am using Qt 4.7.4 on WinXP 32bit

Answer (score 0):

Is `LIBS +=-lsetupapi` in the static lib project or the main project? You might need it in both?

Comment: It is in both project files. I wrote it to question, but somebody edited it - added formating and removed that sentece by accident.